# What does "Should merit the adoption" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

I'm trying to understand the sentence below:

> For another, the complexity of the app state (and possibly the complexity of the team working on the application, as well) should **merit** the adoption. [<sub>(Source)</sub>](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-state-of-the-state-e30e98abdb01)

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context?    
Though **merit** as a verb means : *"deserve or be worthy of (reward, punishment, or attention)"*

Comment: *...should merit (justify) adoption (use) **of the Redux software development method***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for your careful editing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking a guess at the context, but it mentions an "app" (computer application), and "adoption" of a software system means that someone or a company begins using it. The first people who buy into, or begin using an application are often called "[early adopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_adopter)".

In this context, "merit" means *the quality of being particularly good or worthy*.

What the sentence is saying is that "the complexity of the app state" is something that makes the app *worth using*.